# NAT router blocking JMS messages

Tags: client-server, jms, router, nat, openjms

I have an openjms-0-7-7 instance running on my cloud machine. The connection to the jms topic happens over tcp. I run the client application on my personal computer at home and I am able to send messages to the topic (which then get forwarded correctly to other listeners) but I am unable to receive messages. My PC is connected to the internet through a NAT router.
I have tried to reproduce this issue using my university network and it all worked fine (there I am assigned my own external IP address - no NAT).

Am I right thinking that the problem is my router blocking the messages? How can I check this and also, how can I fix this.

Best regards,

Bart

Answer (score 0):

Your router is most probably blocking incoming JMS messages as it does not know to which local client (after NAT) it belongs.

You will have to configure port forwarding in your router. Please refer to its documentation for that. To know which ports to forward, you will have to consult openjms's documentation to see how it assigns ports to clients.